# Spring form tag and model binding escape

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring form tag in my JSP and the model bound to it. I want some inputs inside the form to be received as single @RequestParam values, but whether I put Spring input or plain HTML input the value gets bounded to the model. How can I escape that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put this inside your spring form:

```
<input type="text" id="yourParam" name="yourParam" value="3"/>
```

and you will be able to get the value in your controller with `@RequestParam` without binding it to your model:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/yourMapping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView showForm(@RequestParam String yourParam, YourModelObject yourModelObject...) {
     // You can retrieve here the value of your JSP input

 }
```